# pymongo Query to flat list?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection with "sensors" where each sensor looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c3bfc66b5594738c8016d12"),
    "parentDeviceID" : ObjectId("5c3b9aa0b559471f1088c5e1"),
    "sn" : 2,
}
```

I would like to get a list of serial numbers ("sn") that belong to a particular parentDeviceID:

```
    sensorList = list(self._dbC.sensorsCol.find({'parentDeviceID':parentDeviceID}, {'sn': 1, '_id':0}))
    print(type(sensorList))
    print(sensorList)
```

But I get list of dictionaries:

```
[{'sn': 1}, {'sn': 2}, {'sn': 3}]
```

I would like to get just:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could do it via aggregation, server-side:

```
db.sensors.aggregate({"$group":{"_id":null,"sn":{"$push":"$sn"}}})
```

This will get you a single document like this:

```
{ "_id" : null, "sn" : [1, 2, 3] }
```

It should be trivial to extract the array from that.

The `$group` over `_id:null` means it constructs a single group for all the documents in the collection. The `$push` aggregator constructs an array of all the `sn` values in that group. Be aware that there is a document-size limit of 16 MB, so if your list of sensor ids could get larger than that, you might want a different, client-side solution.